# F-d statistics for spin 3/2 particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

My question is according to Pauli exclusion principal no same energy state gonna occupied by similar spin particles and spin must be add up to zero . For electron it's 1/2 and -1/2 . What about spin 3/2 particles or higher how they gonna arrange in energy states moreover what changes in f-d statistics formula when we change the spin. Is that the g(E)dE or what. ?

Comment: What is the context here? It sounds like you are looking at the statistical mechanics of these particles, is that correct? Where are you getting that spin much add up to zero?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The exclusion principle states that elementary particles with non-integer spin allow only one particle into each spin state, so for 3/2-spin particles there may be one at -3/2, one at -1/2, one at +1/2 and one at +3/2 third spin-component. If the energy statistics is degenerate that would give a maximum 4 (instead of 2 for the electron) in the density of states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pauli's principle only states that no two *fermions* can occupy the same quantum state. It says nothing about the sum of their spins.

I think there's a confusion with the definition of a state. A state *includes* the spin. For example in an atom, an atomic orbital is defined by the triplet $(n,l,m_l)$, which means that $m_s$ is still free to have two values $\pm 1/2$. So you can put two electrons inside it, and their total spin is zero. So far it's correct.

*But an atomic orbital isn't a quantum state.*

A quantum state, in this example, is a quadruplet $(n,l,m_l,m_s)$. Pauli's principe states that you can put only one electron in it, no matter what the spins of the other electrons are, in the same orbital or any other.

Comment: You should add for clarity that the Pauli principle only applies to fermions, not to all particles.

Comment: You're right, I just corrected the first sentence. Thank you.

Comment: So For spin say 3/2 particles. Then each state gonna occupied by 5 distinct ms valued particles is that right?

Comment: No. Each state will be occupied by ONE particle, according to Pauli's principle. Each value of $m_s$ corresponds to a different state.